# Compiling in C in VisualStudio 2010 gives MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010, during a C compile, complains about

> MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019 and fatal error LNK1120

I've read that you must change the configurations of the project under properties-->linker-->subsystem--> Subsystem/Console(/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) but that's not my case.

The code should print a line of text

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {

    printf("As soon as installed, VS2010 can't compile. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong.");

    return 0;

}
```

Include files are correctly installed in the include directory.

---

Edit: the complete error messages are:

> MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

and

> fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved external link

Comment: Please provide an exact error log instead of just pasting the linker error numbers;) Without that, how can others see what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Ok, since the error states that the missing reference is from ___tmainCRTStartup the subsystem should be right. Are you sure the .cpp file that contains main is included in the build? Maybe try add a new source file and copy the contents. The contents pasted here are from a file named crtexe.c/cpp ?

Comment: As soon as I created a new source file and repasted the code, VS2010 suddenly recognized the main function and the errors went away. Strangely, it doesn't work when I use the application wizard.

Comment: I have a feeling you somehow managed to exclude the file from being built, the wizard should work fine.

Comment: I believe that `___tmainCRTStartup` is the main entry point to the C Runtime.  It looks like the C Runtime library is not being linked in.  The Visual Studio IDE should set up all of the necessary paths and such correctly depending on the type of project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated in the question in many cases the issue is because people select wrong project type in the project setup wizard in Visual Studio. Using "Console application" will make the linker look for `_main` while "Windows application" will make the linker look for `_WinMain` (see [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN). However, if the subsystem is right, another simple error that can lead to linking failures is (unknowingly) not defining `_main`. If for some reason `_main` is in your source but is not actually generated (possibilities include the source not being included in the build for some reason, the function being not generated because of some macro definitions that guard it, etc.) you will still get the errors you see.